# how to get Associated Json value based on selected spinner item

Tags: android, json, android-spinner

I have two urls, one for getting the regionname and second for login. the first url gives the response as

```
[{"CmpnyName":"Indore","CmpnyCode":"111"},{"CmpnyName":" Nagpur","CmpnyCode":"222"},{"CmpnyName":" Jabalpur","CmpnyCode":"333"},{"CmpnyName":"Amravati","CmpnyCode":"444"}]
```

now I have to display the CmpnyName in the spinner. So I did as,

```
typeofcompany.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            ba = typeofcompany.getSelectedItem().toString();
            SelectType(ba);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

My problem is when I select the CmpnyName, it should call its associated CmpnyCode for example indore should call 111 and so on....which is to be used in the second url...i am not getting how to do it..any help please....thank u

Comment: first add your json into POJO model, then when you select item from spinner user its position and get your value

Answer (score 0):

First, Parse your Gson string in this way:

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>  companyNameList = new ArrayList<>()
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> companyIdList= new ArrayList<>();

try 
{
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(preferenceManager.getSalaryJobFilter());

                for(int arr = 0; arr<array.length(); arr++){
                  HashMap<String,String>  hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                   HashMap<String,String>  hashMap1 = new HashMap<>();

                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(arr);

                      hashMap.put("companyName",object.getString("companyName"));

             hashMap1.put("companyCode",object.getString("companyCode"));

                    companyNameList .add(hashMap);
                    companyIdList.add(hashMap1);
                }

 } 

 catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Now fill your list from "companyNameList":

```
 for (int i = 0; i < companyNameList.size(); i++) {    
      companyNameSpinnerList.add(companyNameList.get(i).get("companyName"));
    }
   companyNameAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Then use

> > String company_name_id= companyIdList.get(i).get("companyCode");

Inside Ur "onItemSelected" method.
"company_name_id" will be the ID for the selected Company name you needed.

Method 1- Use "companyNameList" array to fill you adapter. Once you click on any item get its position and use "companyIdList" for getting id of it.

Method: 2- You can also use POJO class for it...First get the selected item position, (In ur case its "i") and use it for getting companyid from your POJO

Comment: i added it to my adapter, when i select an item i used getitematposition(i); , i am confused for the next step

Comment: @Arpittodewale - Which solution are u using the HASHMAP one or POJO class..? If you are using POJO then follow "gprathour"  solution. but for this you have to use Custom Adapter not the default one.

And if you are  using HASHMAP solution, then use your position ('i' in ur case ) to get companyid from the "companyIdList".

Comment: m using the HASHMAP one

Comment: @Arpittodewale - I have Updated my answer, Please check. Mark my answer correct, if found it suitable for you

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `bean` class for your model.

```
class MyBean implements java.io.Serializable{
    String companyName;
    String companyCode;

    //getter-setter
}
```

Then set a custom adapter for your Spinner by passing array list of bean classes i.e. `ArrayList<MyBean>`

Then in spinner's onItemSelectedListener do something like,

```
typeofcompany.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        MyBean clickedCompany = myBeanList.get(i);
        // then you can get clickedCompany.getCompanyName();
        // clickedCompany.getCompanyCode();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
});
```